# rendering multiple files - rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rendering

Suppose I make an ajax a call, from which I want to get some static template (app/views/static/some_template.html.erb), on which I want to act with some javascript stored here `app/views/layouts/sign_in.js.erb`. Is it possible to render multiple file ? (because I want to keep separate my js files and my html files)

```
def ajax_call
   respond_to do |format|
    ...
    format.js {render 'layouts/sign_in.js.erb'}
   end
end
```

Edit : here's my controller

```
    respond_to do |format|
       format.js {render 'devise/sessions/new.html.erb'}
    end
```

In `devise/sessions/new.html.erb`, I put

```
<div> test</div>
<%= render "layouts/sign_in.js.erb" %>
```

and in `layouts/sign_in.js.erb`, I put `console.log('test');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is the following

In your controller

```
@template = ActionView::Base.new('app/views/static', {}, ActionController::Base.new).render(file: 'new').to_s

respond_to do |format|
    format.js {render 'layouts/sign_in.js.erb'}
end
```

and then get your `@template` variable back in your `sign_in.js.erb`, `<%= escape_javascript(@template) %>`

Answer (score 2):

You can put renders inside the partial and segment your files one more level:

```
def ajax_call
   respond_to do |format|
    ...
    format.js {render 'layouts/grouped_sign_in.js.erb'}
   end
end

# in _grouped_sign_in.js.erb
<%= render 'layouts/sign_in.js.erb' %>
<%= render 'layouts/create_account.js.erb' %>
```

Comment: In fact, I put a `console.log(test)` inside my `sign_in.js.erb` file, but it seems not to be evaluated as javascript but instead as plain text. How can it be ?

Comment: It still doesn't work I added `<%= javascript_tag do %>console.log("test");<% end %>` and I get `<script>
//<![CDATA[

console.log("test");

//]]>
</script>`

Comment: What is the source code? Can you pastebin it please? I think that there is nested <script> tags, 1 global with 2 inside.

Comment: I reduced the `html` part of the template to `<div>test</div>` and it still get the same problem...

Comment: Perhaps it is related to the fact that I render in my controller some static page `format.js {render 'static/new.html.erb'}` (I put at the bottom of this page `<%= render 'layouts/sign_in.js.erb' %>` )

Comment: Please paste-bin the source code, Can't help you with that few infos

Comment: more simply, is there a way to store the html content of the static page inside some variable in the controller ?